# I forgot the passcode for my iPad restrictions. How can I disable them?

Tags: ipad, password

I added restrictions to my iPad and I forgot the passcode for them, now what? Is there a way to remove it without resetting the device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is wipe the device and then start over. If you have a backup, hopefully it's from before the restrictions were set.

Comment: The long answer?

Comment: The long answer is you can try to use a previous “backup” of your device which usually don’t have the initial password, but the other settings I don’t think they are preserved unencrypted, that’s why I didn’t suggest you that. The best way tho’ it’s to restore.

Answer (score 6):

There's a tool that can recover the restrictions passcode from a device backup, called *pinfinder*. Download the tool at the [pinfinder github page](https://github.com/gwatts/pinfinder), make an **unencrypted** backup and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304):

> If you lose or forget your Restrictions passcode, you'll need to erase
>   your device and then set it up as a new device to remove the passcode.
>   Restoring the device won't remove the passcode.

So apparently restoring from a "pre restrictions" backup won't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively one can use Forgot iPhone via iCloud to Erase their phone if the problem is similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240120/iphone-locked-out-due-to-restrictions)

This will wipe your entire data and you can setup your iPhone as new.