# Can not restore my iPhone 5 because of restriction passcode

Tags: restore, iphone

I was half asleep when I put a restriction passcode on for my child to play on it.

I went to restore it so I have to turn off "find my phone " but I can't because of the restrictions. How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/i-forgot-the-passcode-for-my-ipad-restrictions-how-can-i-disable-them . It is for the iPad, but I think the same applies

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this Github project to recover restrictions passcode from an unencrypted backup.
https://github.com/gwatts/pinfinder/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

> The short answer is no.
>
> The long answer is wipe the device and then start over. If you have a backup, hopefully it's from before the restrictions were set.

---

Quote from Martin Marconcini's answer on the possible duplicate post as mentioned in the comments.